# Firebase Functions to GCE firewall rule

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine

I have some firebase functions that have to connect to a REST service running on a GCE machine in GCP (under the same project of course). The firewall is blocking the connection and the only way to make it happen was to open the port to everybody.

Does anybody know how can you specify firebase functions as source in a firewall rule?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Service account](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) in a source of firewall rule. Service account which is associated with you Fire-base Cloud function. Following steps will

- Go the google cloud console and select with project name.
- Go to the IAM section and find your service account with
  (name="Google Cloud Functions Service Agent" and has @gcf.***.com)
- Link this service account with firewall rule source.

Comment: Aha, thanks. Worth noting, the Service Account selector under firewall rules shows only User Defined Service Accounts. I had to select from "Other Project" to be able to add the functions Service Account (which is Google Managed).

Comment: as @VictorG mentioned you can not choose service account for "Google Cloud Functions", it is not in list. And if you select "In another project" and copy-paste service account's email, this will not give any result