# CORS issue with onCall firebase cloud functions (GCP firewall rules)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Two years ago I deployed a project involving several firebase cloud functions some of which are called through the use of database triggers, and 3 by the use of the “functions.https.onCall…” trigger (“callable” functions).

Everything worked perfectly after deployment, however, around October 2019, I had to abandon the project, and I did not keep maintaining it.

Currently, I’m interested on getting the site fully working again, so I followed all of the necessary steps listed on the emails I got, such as updating my node.js version, the firebase admin and functions version, and so on; however after redeploying the functions, only those with database triggers seem to be working.
(Please note that the functions weren’t modified whatsoever from the time they were working.)

The error I’m getting on the browser console for the functions that don’t work is:

*Access to fetch at 'https://…/functionName' from origin 'https://….com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.*

After some testing and retracing of my steps **I’ve been able to pinpoint exactly what the problem is, however, I have been unable to fix it quite yet.**

Basically, I noticed that the way permissions are handled on GCP have changed since I first deployed the project, given that I now had to, for instance, add firewall rules to even be able to run the instances I previously used to without doing so. So, it occurred to me that it could very well be **the firewall itself that is blocking the functions from connecting to the virtual machine instance on GCP**, thus, preventing the completion of the function runtime, and causing the error.

*Accordingly, I decided to test this by **granting open access to the instance** by specifying 0.0.0.0/0 as the source IP range for ingress to the target tag related to the virtual machine, and immediately after, all functions were **fully functional again.***

The thing is that, for obvious reasons, I really wouldn’t want to leave open access to the instance, but I haven’t been able to establish a successful connection through any other methods.

I read the pages for:

Access Control:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam

Configuring network settings:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings

Cloud Functions IAM Roles:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configuration

And additionally:
[Firebase Functions to GCE firewall rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54440490/firebase-functions-to-gce-firewall-rule)

And, from what I’ve gathered, what I’m looking for is to **set the firewall rule so that the service account related to the app has permissions enabled**. However, I haven’t managed to do this yet as:

•   First of all, selecting “specified target tags” on the Firewall rule details (as I did for IP ranges) disables “Service account” as a Source filter.

•   Setting “All instances in the network” as a target, “Service account” as a source filter, and the “App Engine default service account” (…@appspot.gserviceaccount.com), or “firebase-adminsdk” (firebase-adminsdk-…@....iam.gserviceaccount.com) as the “Source Service account”; didn't grant the permissions necessary, as the functions went back to not working.
For this last option I even followed the steps outlined in:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configuration
For the project Runtime Service Account: …@appspot.gserviceaccount.com; but nothing changed.

•   Finally, selecting the other available options as a “Source Service account” (Compute Engine default service account) didn’t enable the connection either.

**In summary: The only necessary step to finish fixing the issue would be to find a way in which I could call the VM in GCP, from firebase cloud functions without granting access to all IPs; just the functions (so I assume the admin account related?).**

Additionally just in case:

After checking my firebase console settings, I noticed that I had the following warning:
*“Your project is missing a service account for use with the firebase Admin SDKs”*
(despite the fact that during the original deployment of the project, one was created. I’ll call it firebase-adminsdk-A@proyect.iam.gserviceaccount.com)

So, I went through the procedure of creating a new one: firebase-adminsdk-B@proyect.iam.gserviceaccount.com, and adding the key to the functions, however, this new account doesn’t grant the necessary permissions on the firewall either.
Moreover, I now have 2 firebase service accounts under “firebase-adminsdk” in the firewall options:

firebase-adminsdk-A@proyect.iam.gserviceaccount.com

firebase-adminsdk-B@proyect.iam.gserviceaccount.com

None of which solve the CORS issue upon being selected.

I don’t know if it’s the lack of detection of the first service account on the firebase console that could be causing the issue.

Finally, if this is somehow relevant:

I tried some solutions I found online, such as checking that all permissions for the functions on the cloud functions console for the “Cloud Functions Invoker” were set to allUsers, and redeploying all functions; but this made no difference.

(https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/645#issuecomment-605835353)
(https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation)

Also, after reading:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

*“Caution: New HTTP and HTTP callable functions deployed with any Firebase CLI lower than version 7.7.0 are private by default and throw HTTP 403 errors when invoked. Either explicitly make these functions public or update your Firebase CLI before you deploy any new functions.”*

I updated my Firebase CLI to the latest version and redeployed all functions once more.

Sorry for the wall of text but I wanted to be as thorough as possible given that it seems a fairly specific issue. (Firebase support wasn´t able to give me a solution)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly but I think the easiest solution to this is using a [**VPC Serverles connector**](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access).

When you create a *VPC Serverless Connector*, resources like App Engine, Cloud Run and in your case, Cloud Functions, can connect to resources inside a VPC like a VM.

From what I've read, your having a hard time with the firewall settings, service accounts and all that stuff. So, when you create a *VPC Serverless Connector* (you can follow this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/connecting-vpc) to create one), you can use it to connect to your VM using their Internal IPs, for example:

Let's say you have 2 VMs with Internal IPs `10.128.0.2` & `10.128.0.3`. Then, making the CF [use the VPC Serverless Connector](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#route-egress-to-vpc) for egress traffic to internal resources, you can call those VMs using their internal IP's from your Functions code (When creating the function remember to use `Route only requests to private IPs through the VPC connector` so only the traffic to reach internal resources uses the VPC).

And for the firewall, you only have to grant access from the *VPC Serverless Connector* CIDR you configured when you created it. If you used for example, `10.8.0.0/28`, you will only have to grant access to the VM's from that CIDR range in the selected ports (like the `80`, `8080`, `443` or any you need to use) and with that, you don't have to allow access from `0.0.0.0/0` which is not ideal for you.

Try this and hope it helps c:

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and found a simple solution - the deployed onCall Cloud Function returns 403 and the browser says "CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing".

It turns out that the function works if I manually grant "allUsers" a role "Cloud Function Invoker" in the function's permission tab:
[image]